# asp.net Webforms: how to send POST request from One page and Read POSTed response on a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, httpresponse, .net-4.6.2

I wish to know how we can read the POST response in the below scenario… Specifically, is there a way to achieve the below scenario:

I have one asp.net (4.6) webforms application: “App1”

It has 2 pages: “Page1.aspx”,
“Page2.aspx”

App1------> POSTs data to some URL (ThirdParty)---- from Page1.aspx
(using WebRequest Class)

That third Party app POSTs back a data (JSON format ) to the URL we
specify. (this is Page2.aspx)

Now, how to read that data sent on the Page2.aspx.

How to achieve this control flow?

Many Thanks!

Comment: How are you POSTing the data to said third party?

Comment: Hi S.Walker, please find below:

Comment: byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);  
HttpWebRequest httprequest = (WebRequest.Create(ThirdPartyURL) as HttpWebRequest);  
httprequest.Method = "POST";  
httprequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencode";  
httprequest.ContentLength = data.Length;  
Stream stream = httprequest.GetRequestStream();  
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  
stream.Close();

Comment: I don’t think the third-party URL is going to be able to respond with data to Page2 directly. Because Page1 is the “caller” the remote site will respond to Page1. After stream.close(), you will need to POST the data to Page2 independently. Does that make sense? The process will need to be Page1 -> Remote Site -> Page 1 copies response and forwards -> Page 2

Comment: Many Thanks S.Walker for your response! Yes it makes sense!! However, the thirdparty  has requested us for an URL that it would use to POST the Response (response in the sense of "Answer" to our "Question" - This response would be a Independent POST request from their ends to our system with Page2.aspx as endpoint). And on our ends we are supposed to read the POSTED "Response/Answer" to us on Page2.aspx. Is this achievable in WebForms?

Comment: This sounds like a version of the webhook pattern. There's no reason it shouldn't be achievable

Comment: @swan4dotnet - Sorry just seeing this. Did you get this worked out? If not, does your page 2 have any server side code? If so when you call the third party API with response endpoint, your server side code for Page 2 should be executing.

Comment: Hi S.Walker! Thanks for checking. Yes, page2 has server-side code, I am trying to check with Request.form["expected-field-name"], however, the page (Page_Load) wont get invoked in first place. I am now trying to replicate the behaviour of ThirdParty tool, by creating a simple WebAPI on my local machine to talk to. So.. the flow would as: Page1.aspx POSTS to ---> API, (POSTS back) ---> Page2. This is not working yet, may be cos, both are on Localhost using same port. Any references how one can have 2 web apps on localhost and communicate with http POST with IIS?

Comment: Hi ADyson! Thanks for your message. I tried going through WebHook pattern, though sounds similar, I am unsure if I want to use it. But definitely was a new and good concept for me to know!!

Comment: It doesn't matter if you want to use it or not here. You're being asked to use it (or something quite similar). The point is there's no reason why what this third party is asking for wouldn't be possible. You might be better with a webmethod or simple wcf service within your application rather than an aspx page though, to receive a machine initiated request

Comment: P.s. to run two web applications on the same host in IIS you either put them in separate virtual directories so they have different URLs or you create two separate sites within IIS so they are running on different ports

Comment: Yes ADyson! Thanks!!